# TypeScript Error Cannot find module 'angularfire2/interfaces' ionic 3 angularfire2-offline

Tags: typescript, firebase, ionic3, angularfire2, angularfire2-offline

When I want to setup angularfire2-offline I get this error:

```
[16:02:08]  typescript: node_modules/angularfire2-offline/database/database.d.ts, line: 2 
            Cannot find module 'angularfire2/interfaces'. 

       L1:  import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
       L2:  import { FirebaseListFactoryOpts, FirebaseObjectFactoryOpts } from 'angularfire2/interfaces';
       L3:  import { AfoListObservable } from './list/afo-list-observable';

[16:02:08]  typescript: node_modules/angularfire2-offline/database/interfaces.d.ts, line: 1 
            Cannot find module 'angularfire2/interfaces'. 

       L1:  import { FirebaseListFactoryOpts } from 'angularfire2/interfaces';

[16:02:08]  typescript: node_modules/angularfire2-offline/database/list/afo-list-observable.d.ts, line: 1 
            Cannot find module 'angularfire2/interfaces'. 

       L1:  import { FirebaseListFactoryOpts } from 'angularfire2/interfaces';
       L2:  import { ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs/ReplaySubject';

[16:02:08]  typescript: node_modules/angularfire2-offline/database/list/emulate-query.d.ts, line: 1 
            Cannot find module 'angularfire2/interfaces'. 

       L1:  import { FirebaseListFactoryOpts } from 'angularfire2/interfaces';
       L2:  export declare class EmulateQuery {
```

`@ngModule` in `app.module.ts`:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig),
    AngularFireDatabaseModule,
    AngularFireOfflineModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Versions:

- Ionic 3.9.2
- CLI 3.8
- angularfire2 4.0.0
- angularfire2-offline 4.2.4
- firebase 4.3.0
- typescript 2.6.0

I was following the two tutorials:

https://github.com/adriancarriger/angularfire2-offline
and
https://javebratt.com/offline-angularfire2/

The error suddenly occured.

Comment: Can you show the `code` of `NgModule` section?

Comment: `@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig),
    AngularFireDatabaseModule,
    AngularFireOfflineModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}`

Comment: Please put that on your post.Then everyone can read it nicely.Here can't.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be a problem with the new angularfire2 version

angularfire2 : 4.0.0-rc.2

I did a downgrade to previous version and now everything works fine.

```
npm install angularfire2@4.0.0-rc0
```

Comment: Removing AngularFireModule from providers in app.module.ts is fixed for me.